# Create news website with data visualizations in Django

Tags: django, database, d3.js, tinymce

I'm trying to make a website that I can post articles to. The articles will have various d3.js visualizations or something like this:

1. https://www.latimes.com/projects/star-wars-most-talkative-characters/
2. https://www.latimes.com/projects/rams-chargers-fan-map-la/

The site will have less than 500 visitors, and security is not a concern. I plan to upload articles once a day, so uploading should be simple. I'm currently planning on using Django for the backend, d3.JS for visualizations, and some database to store articles in, etc. I'm planning on using a rich text editor plugin such as TinyMCE to format the pages.

My only Django experience is the tutorial series in the documentation, so I'm not sure if this is the right set of tools for the job. Is there a better way to store an article that contains graphs, images, interactive visualizations, etc. in a database? Is there a better way to structure what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use Django (awesome framework) or any other framework/CMS you want, the thing is it will always depends on your data types that you are using, for example if you have GeoJSON/topoJSON for visualization data its better to store them in a file and serve them through web server say for example Nginx (good for serving static data), and this is better than having them stored inside PostgreSQL or MySQL.